# How would you guys call a class to instantiate both NPCs and players?

Tags: character

My idea is having a class to instantiate both NPCs and players. I have thought of some names like Entity but that is way too broad, as it could refer to anything from a block to an event really. I've also thought of Character, but that name seems to refer to only important characters in the story, not any NPC that you might encounter in the world.
It's a pretty straightforward question, yet I've been racking my brain for about an hour and can't seem to get any useful ideas.

Thanks guys, and peace.

Comment: Call it Actor, it's very common.

Comment: @Babis Actor seems legit, and that can hold both players and any other character there is. Post an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Somebody is probably going to flag this question because it has way too many possible answers and/or is opinion based, but I'd like to chip in anyway. I call mine "Unit"

Comment: @Peethor Unit seems legit too man. Still prefer Actor as unit can define a lot of stuff too. Like a Family Unit or ya know.

Comment: I often used to call mine "Character", but depending on the language you use it may conflict with already existing classes which is annoying.

Comment: @Khopa Coding in C++ there isn't that problem. But I still choose not to call mine Characters for the reason posed above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Actor
{
   Vector3 position;
   ect..;
   ect..;
};
class PlayerCharacter : public Actor
{
   //input stuff
};
class NonPlayerCharacter : public Actor
{
   //AI stuff
};
```

Comment: So an non player character is a player character. Nice theory. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: You editted it. Excuse my non sense.

Answer (score 1):

In Unity Game Engine, I like to use a factory to create these objects;

```
class ObjectManager{
    public GameObject CreatePlayer() {
        ...
    }
    public GameObject CreateNpc() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Just attach Different Component to GameObject to make players or npcs.

```
public GameObject CreatePlayer() {
    var g = new GameObject();
    g.AddComponent<PlayerAI>();
    return g;
```

}

```
public GameObject CreateNpc() {
   var g = new GameObject();
   g.AddComponent<NpcAI>();
   return g;
```

}

Comment: I use C++ though. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the class name :   [Dude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dude)

Comment: I guess that is as broad as Entity, yet it is quite funny. If I was deving the game alone, I'd use that name, but I'm working with a team currently. Thanks for the help anyways.